# How to organize my code (methods I create for various uses on my website)

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, webforms

I wrote some code to connect the application to it's database, then I created some code to use the connection code and retrieve, update or add some values to the database, Also I might have some code to deal with other stuff than to deal with the database

The code is a little complicated, maybe it's simple but it's not short, for example to write a good piece of code to just retrieve a single value so I could set the controller with this value I used this :

```
SqlConnection sqlconnection= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM message  WHERE id = 3", sqlconnection);

        try
        {
            sqlconnection.Open();
            lbl_name.Text = (string)sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar();
            Status.Text = "Done";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Status.Text = ex.Message;
        }

        finally
        {
            sqlconnection.Close();
        }
```

I might even add some code to store some info in the database about any exception is thrown, I think the code is pretty basic, yet it's not small, given that it's the smallest piece I'll need, some huge code is written for adding or editing new items, and also consider that it's not the only code I'll write in the page, the page has more needs :D!

I've provided a detailed case I hope!...So what do you think will be the best way to make my page fast and easy to read and have an organized code
I've started placing every code in an appropriate method, but some methods are common so I create them again in every page that needs them like a ConnectionToDataBase Method, and mean while I think I just organized the page so I could mainly look at Page_Load and see what are the called methods and then scroll down to read the definition but It's still a big page and note the best practice I think

Sorry for all the big question, I just provide details so I could get a reasonable answer for my question, I hope everyone benefits from it as most questions are pretty basic, newbies like me needs some detailed cases and answers to get a better start...Thanks for your time!

**EDIT:** I know I'm new, So any comments on my code are more than welcome!

Comment: Kind of hard to understand exactly what you are asking here. However, i don't like the idea of having a "ConnectionToDataBase" method on every page. Maybe rethink your project structure, can you create a DAL?

Comment: I know, it's new and all overwhelming sorry about that!   I'd love to and I know it's not good at all to have a method that do the same functionality created more than once, but I've gained some experience writing very newbie code, but concepts and best practice and safety code I'm pertty ignorant about that, but I'd love to learn to write a good code for my websites, do you know any articles or books that might help with my issue !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some quick observations:

1. Do not use inline SQL, since it's a bear to maintain (go with Stored Procedures or if you're doing basic CRUD operations, consider an ORM)

Also (Per the comment below, which is very relevant) if you MUST use inline SQL, in cases where you end up concatonating your values into a command text, you can be leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks (and in general you should avoid inline SQL in any case).

1. Do not globally capture and swallow exceptions - only capture exceptions where you are actually handling them - otherwise, bubble them back up.
2. You will want to either abstract your data access code into a data access layer independent of your business object (I'm a fan of a repository pattern), or (preferrably) consider an ORM (I strongly recommend NHibernate, possibly Entity Framework 4 which has much nicer POCO support).

Generally how I structure this kind of data is have a business object have a reference to a repository object - this is defined as an interface, so I can swap out my test and real implementations via dependency injection.

The data repository then does the relevant heavy lifting (generally via an ORM, sometimes in ADO.Net for some of our legacy code) - so if I needed a list of customers, I would just call a 'GetCustomers' method on the repository.  The business layer has no knowledge of data access, it just knows that when it calls a method it gets back a nice strongly typed list.

[Answering the request RE organization]

When I use this pattern for an MVC website, I generally have my controller invoke a business logic class.  It's purpose in life is to encapsulate the non-data specific calculations, etc. that it retrieves from my data access layer.

The business logic class will, in turn, reference one or more repositories that encapsulate data transport between my data, and my business classes (things like saving/retrieving data, etc.).

The repository is responsible for serving up the data (again, ADO.Net, NHibernate, EF, whatever works for you).  It should have no business logic, just enough to take the data from my database, shape it appropriately, and return basic non-data specific objects back to the business layer.

I have some samples on this organization on my blog (available in my profile) that while they are NHibernate specific, show a pretty basic useage of a repository pattern.

Hope that helps out :)

Comment: Extra note on #1 - don't forget SQL injection attacks. If you MUST use inline SQL, as least parameterize it.

Comment: Excellent comment :)  Was going to add the bit on SQL Injection as well.

Comment: I think your answer doesn't have anything to do with providing a solution to organize my code and methods, But I think the information is very great for me and many other newbies so +1 Thanks a lot Bob.

Comment: Thanks RPM, and any comments on my code are very welcome, I'd appreciate the experience and listen well so that was very useful

Comment: @IKashef - no worries. I think you should re-word your question to highlight the fact you need help to organize your code and methods. As i said in my other comment, take a look at having a DAL (Data Access Layer) or (my favourite) Repository. This is essentially another project in your solution (Class Library), which the UI can talk to. Allows isolation of persistence code from your UI.

Comment: @RPM1984 I didn't get exactly what you wanted to say about my question, I'm asking how to organize my code, what did you want to say exactly ? I've seen some articles about DAL but Repository is not familiar I'll read about them both and hope to know why repository is your favorite ?

Comment: @Bob Palmer that would help and yeah it's much more clear now but I wish I could get a book or a series of articles that shows concepts and practices such as DAL and Repository, and sorry I forgot to mention I'm using web forms not mvc!

Comment: @IKashef - there is far too much information on design patterns here to go into. Here's an article on Repository pattern that i love: http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/

Comment: The point of a DAL/Repository (in short), is so your UI does this: `repository.GetSomeData(1)`. Not `SqlCommand = new Sql..`. Your UI should know NOTHING about the persistence layer. It should only know "I need to get some stuff, i don't care where it comes from, just get it for me. Here is an ID of the stuff i want". Then it's up to the repository/DAL to fetch the data for the UI.

Comment: Thanks that was great and I'll start reading about the design patterns subject, I got the concept and I'll dive to the core of the subject. but from Bob's answer I think that he doesn't think that the classes I'm using to communicate with the database are the best tool, he mentioned a lot of other stuff ( ADO.Net, NHibernate, EF, ORM ) what's your opinion ? and one last thing!! is it good to use Frameworks or Third-Party classes and tools in my application as a professional developer ?